# Getting size information before the end of a show animation

Tags: jquery, css, animation, show

When using jQuery.show(), is there a way to access information about how big the shown element will be before the animation has taken place?

*edit - thought I'd give an example of where I plan to use this as any work-around not doing directly what I've asked would still be very useful:

Content inside a lightbox is expanded using .show(), but the lightbox size and positioning have to wait for the end of the animation before measuring the new dimensions and adjusting. The result being two animations following each other, when what I want is 2 animations running concurrently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$("some element").css({
display: "block", visibility: "hidden", position: "absolute"
});

Will cause the element to take it's natural size but remain hidden. You can then measure the dimensions of the element in safety using .height() and .width()

Hope that helps.

Comment: This, then use [outerHeight](http://api.jquery.com/outerHeight/) and/or [outerWidth](http://api.jquery.com/outerWidth/)

Comment: I'll give this a go. Sounds like it should work, although I'm a bit worried about the effect of position:absolute, particularly in ie6 & 7 where the browser's interpretation of where and how big to render elements seems to break sometimes when using position:absolute without specifying left, top etc.

Comment: don't worry too much about it while the element is invisible, you'll need to override those styles afterwards or set them in css beforehand. There's lots of approaches you can use to achieve the end result.

Answer (score 0):

You can have the following:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   var beforeHeight = $('#element').height();
   $('#element').animate({
      height:350
   },250, function() {
      var afterHeight = $('#element').height();
   });

   alert("Before: "+beforeHeight+" \r\n After: " + afterHeight);
});
```

Just re-read you question - if you want 2 animations, one after the other:

```
$('#element').animate({
    //animate stuff
},250,function() {
   $('#element').animate({
      //animate more stuff
   },250)
});
```

Answer (score -1):

If I understand the question correctly, below should do it.

```
var height = $("#foo").height();
```

Comment: The trouble is that before the animation $("#foo").height() is often (always?) 0, so it's not a good measure of what the height will be after the animation